# Swoole Install error

Tags: php, macos, swoole

I am trying install swoole on my mac
I tried this
    `sudo pecl install swoole`

But am getting an error like this
fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found first.

How to solve this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: try the compile method https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/wiki/Installing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
brew install swoole 
#!/bin/bash
brew install homebrew/php/php71-swoole
```

also try this

```
pecl download swoole
tar xvf swoole-1.7.9.tgz
cd swoole-1.7.9
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

you need install `pcre-dev` at first

Answer (score 0):

`pcre.h` is a dependency for php Swoole extension .

Resolve this issue by installing the `PCRE`

- 1 - Install Homebrew :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

- 2 - Install `PCRE`

```
brew install pcre
```

- 3 - Try Installing `Swoole` Again

```
sudo pecl install swoole
```